# MVC routing with Angular 12 Integrated with build

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

I have migrated an angularjs with mvc into angular with mvc.

The issue is mvc routing doesn't work with parameter.It returns 404 page. I tried with # but, route gets sliced till # and only that route works.

[image]

AdminIndex is a mvc action. followed by routeDashboard,mvc takes it as paramter. But the route highlighted,I need to pass an id to angular which shows 404.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are a few things to be changed in your routes array.

Try to remove all pathMatch properties except on the last object with redirect.

Then I would have placed the canActivate property on each route and remove it from the last one with redirect.

So that your array would look something like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "AdminIndex/routeDashboardff", component: DashboardffComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuardGuard]},
  ...
  ...
  {path: "**", redirectTo: "AdminIndex/routeDashboardff", pathMatch: "full"}
];
```

Comment: I removed pathMatch property from other routes and canactivate,i have written for a logic. Still faced same issue. Have updated the error image.

Comment: Where have you defined the first part of the route you have in the url bar?
"FactFind/FFHome"

Comment: I have done the same in base="/FactFind/FFHome" and also in app.module as APP_BASE_HREF

Comment: Are the angular application running in the terminal?
And is the port correct?

Comment: I running the angular application with mvc project using angular build. So angular build will be connected to mvc project

Answer (score 0):

I used queryparams instead of dynamic params in url.

Passed the values like route?Id=1 instead of route/:Id. This fixed my issue while redirecting.

Thanks everyone for your valuable time